# After configuring a Manifest for an App Registration in AzureAD, I am unable to save the Manifest

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am an owner of an App Registration in AzureAD.   The SAVE button is greyed out when I try to save the manifest.  I am able to get an error if I upload the manifest. The error is generic, "Failed to save manifest."   I am looking for a troubleshooting path. I will not turn down solutions either.

I've added myself as an Application Administrator, but it didn't work.

Comment: After fixing a missing comma in my manifest, the save button lit up and was available.   The manifest is still erroring but now I have an Error detail.  "One or more properties conatins invalid values."   That I can work with.

Comment: If the issue has been solved, you could post your answer here to help others.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you modified.

Please double-check the content comparison before and after the modification to locate the properties that may be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to upload a previously downloaded manifest, you may see the above error. This is likely because **the manifest editor now supports a newer version of the schema, which doesn't match with the one you're trying to upload**. We recommend try the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#common-issues).

1.Edit the attributes individually in the `manifest editor` instead of uploading a previously downloaded manifest. Use the manifest reference table to understand the syntax and semantics of old and new attributes so that you can successfully edit the attributes you're interested in.

2.If your workflow requires you to save the manifests in your source repository for use later, we suggest rebasing the saved manifests in your repository with the one you see in the **App registrations** experience.

Here is a similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57630918/azure-portal-error-while-trying-to-change-client-app-scopes/57651371#57651371) you could refer to.