# Azure portal error while trying to change client app scopes

Tags: azure, authentication

I have several client apps registered in the Azure portal.  Each app has different scopes that are enabled/disabled.  I used to be able to modify the scopes and save the updates for each of the register apps. Now I get the following error from the Azure portal:

*Failed to update {my app} application. Error detail: Property identifierUris is invalid. [mURNc]*

I also get this same error even if all I try to do is rename the client app.  If I create a brand new app there are no issues.  This appears to be a bug in the azure portal, but I'm looking for a workaround as I don't want to redefine all the scopes again, there are quite a few!

I've tried to rename things, change the client app ID, etc, but nothing seems to fix the issue, I get the same error.  Again, this all used to work fine and now suddenly with no changes I get this issue.

The error says the identifierUris is invalid, but it isn't descriptive at all on which URI it is referring to.  Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Comment: Oh you are the second person to ask this in a short time :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear this.  Perhaps it is a temporary issue affecting not just me.

Comment: Seems like there is now a "new experience" in the Authentication tab of app registrations. Could be related.

Comment: I see what you're talking about @juunas, could be!  I missed that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As junnas said, click `try out the new experience` in the Authentication tab of App registration and try again.

Also, when you see the above error, we recommend the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest):

1.Edit the attributes individually in the [manifest editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#manifest-reference) instead of uploading a previously downloaded manifest. Use the manifest reference table to understand the syntax and semantics of old and new attributes so that you can successfully edit the attributes you're interested in.

2.If your workflow requires you to save the manifests in your source repository for use later, we suggest rebasing the saved manifests in your repository with the one you see in the **App registrations** experience.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Leon.  I previously tried to switch to "try out the new experience" as juunas suggested, but unfortunately I continued to get the same error.

I hadn't thought of trying out the manifest editor though.  I see only one reference to identifierUris in the manifest, which is referring to the api name.  Instead of the default "api://{some guid}}" I had changed it to "api://hapi-fhir-dstu3-rest-api".  Is this invalid?  If I try to change it to "api://ba2ef3d4-984e-44a5-af15-26c6393eca9a" or anything else it gives me the exact same error (indentifierUris is invalid)

Comment: It seems this app registration is corrupt for some reason, since I can't change anything.  Unfortunately, looks like I'll have to create a brand new app registration and copy/paste sections of the manifest from the old one to the new one.  I wish I knew what corrupted this app registration at least, so I don't repeat the mistake.

Comment: Leon, your suggestion of exporting the manifest and then copy/pasting the relevant sections into a brand new client app worked.  Still not happy the original one got corrupted and I have no idea why, but at least I have a workaround.